# Newbie questions: Calculating the time to discharge for a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, inductor, discharge

I am looking to charge a capacitor using a simple DC power supply. however, I was curious how I could calculate the time until my capacitors would discharge.

Also, would an inductor placed in series at the output of the capacitor affect charging time? In my model, I have a small 2.5 mH inductor placed at the output.

Here is the schematic that I will be using for my circuit if it provides any insight. please note that the transformer will be kept at as low of an inductance as possible.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic indicates that you plan to work with very high, quite lethal voltages, but your question suggests that you are very inexperienced with electronics, and your user name doesn't inspire a lot of confidence either. Please back off from this project. Start working with low voltages and learn your way safely. We want you to be an active member of the EE community for many years to come.

Answer (score 1):

In theory forever, there is no off state discharge path.

In this application, for safety, you should provide a high value bleed resistor across the capacitor then your discharge time is determined by that value the capacitor value your start voltage and at what voltage you consider the capacitor discharged.

Comment: Greetings, if I were to place a resistor of say 1000 ohms before the capacitor set, how could I calculate this discharge time/time to charge up?

Comment: Do a search on this site for "calculate capacitor discharge time" take heed of the warning by Elliot above you need to do a lot more research before undertaking this project.